# in extjs4 How to get menu items of one view in another view to enable it

Tags: view, menu, extjs4

I am working in extjs. I have libraryCentralPanel view as-

```
Ext.define('R.view.library.LibraryCenterPanel', {
alias:'widget.centralPanel',
initcomponent:function()
{
 var me = this;
 this.items = [{
 xtype: 'librarylistview',
 id:'librarylistview'
        }]; 
 me.fileMenu = Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
  ........ 
  }
}
```

and above librarylistview which is included as xtype is having code as-

```
Ext.define('R.view.library.LibraryListView',{
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias : 'widget.librarylistview',
    store: 'LibraryFileStore',

  selModel:Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel', {
  headerWidth: 40,
  showHeaderCheckbox: false,
  ignoreRightMouseSelection : false,

   listeners:{
        'select':function(record, index, e ){
    }
    }),
```

so i want to enable filemenu only on selection of checkbox.otherwise i want to keep it as disable. So how to get this fileMenu of librarycentralpanel in my LibraryListView and how to make it enable there on checkbox selection. Please can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

enabling and disabling elements is pretty easy...

within your listener function, simply query the element you want to enable/disable:

```
...
if(checkboxValue){
    Ext.ComponentQuery.query('centralPanel')[0].enable();
}else{
    Ext.ComponentQuery.query('centralPanel')[0].disable();
}
...
```